# Prove if $f$ is entire and $|f(z)| \leq |z|^{1/2}$ for all $z$, then $f(z) = 0$ for all $z$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove if $f$ is entire and $|f(z)| \leq |z|^{1/2}$ for all $z$ in the complex plane, then $f(z) = 0$.  This was given on a homework assignment, but I have no idea how to do it! A walkthrough would be wonderful!

Answer (score 1):

$f(0)=0$ so it suffices to show that $f$ is constant.

Here is a hint:  Take the power series representation for $f$ about $0$ and use the fact that each coefficient in the power series can be written as an integral over the circle of radius $r>0$ using Cauchy's formula.  Then show that the limit of these integrals as $r\to \infty$ is zero.  Since this is homework I will leave the details to you.

Comment: We went over Taylor Series. But I do not see how we can write f(z) as a series unless you mean the general formula of the sum from n to infinity of $a_n(z)^n$. where $a_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$. So, are we suppose to use cauchy's differentiation formula? I was absent for a day and so it has been hard to catch up.

Comment: Have you seen the proof of Liouville's theorem?  The argument is almost identical.

Comment: I don't think so. I don't see it in my notes or book.

Comment: That is shocking.

Comment: I'll try looking at one online and moving from there. Thanks for the lead!

Comment: I'd definitely look more carefully in your book.  I can't believe there is a text on complex analysis that doesn't include the proof.  Look up "Cauchy's formula" for the integral equation I am talking about.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula